Which one is generally more computationally- and memory-efficient - ee.reduceRegions or ee.sampleRegions?
For the following hypothetical scenario:

assuming 10000 points (geometry file) with a tileScale of 1 or 2
that are spread across the globe

I'm interesting to appending the ImageCollection bands info from the pixels that these point geometries fall into in the most memory and computationally efficient manner.
In this scenario, is ee.reduceRegions with reducer=ee.Reducer.first().forEach(image.bandNames()) as the reducer argument to fetch the pixel value is the more efficient one or the ee.sampleRegions? and why?
